# ENTITY truncando valor decimal ao fazer SELECT

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho a seguinte situação,

Ao executar uma consulta utilizando LINQ, tenho o seguinte retorno **5178560,00**
mas se executo a mesma consulta, direto no SQL SERVER, ele me retorna **5179975,00**.

Não é um problema de exibição... ele ja me traz isso do banco dessa maneira, antes mesmo de efetuar alguma operação com o campo.

Como proceder, para trazer esse valor, na forma pura do banco?

Comment: Acho que tem algo de errado na sua interpretação das coisas. Se as casas decimais tiverem algum valor, elas são mostradas corretamente?

Comment: É uma lista de valores decimais, composta por 123 itens, nenhum dos itens possui valor quebrado.. quando executo a mesma consulta direto no SQL server, é retornado um valor, quando executo a mesma consulta pelo LINQ, ele efetua essa alteração de valor ao trazer os dados.

Comment: Você poderia compartilhar o código SQL e C# que está usando?

Comment: Segue o código:
http://pastebin.com/RvuHGShG

A lista de dados : http://pastebin.com/BfUizwfh

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Seria bom você editar um dos dados com o valor quebrado pra testar.

Comment: Tente utilizar no banco, Decimal (7,2) no campo do valor.